# nginx doesn't serve files

Tags: debian, services, nginx

I have copied a directory into `/var/www` named `mysite`; then I created a file in `sites-available` in order to setup configuration to point to this directory (`/etc/nginx/sites-available/mysite`) and a symlink of it in `sites-enabled` (`/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/mysite`):

```
server {
    listen 4000 default_server;
    listen [::]:4000 default_server;

    root /var/www/otsui;

    index index.html;

    server_name _;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

}
```

But when I try to get `http://localhost:4000/`, I get `This site can’t be reached` page which means nothing is being served.

I have also tried restarting `nginx` service.

I have a debian jessie.

These are my firewalls:

```
root@mylab:/var/www# iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DOCKER-USER  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
DOCKER-ISOLATION  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
DOCKER     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
DOCKER     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain DOCKER (2 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain DOCKER-ISOLATION (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain DOCKER-USER (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
```

I have also tried copying my web-site files into the default directory, i.e. `/var/www/html`; but navigating to `http://127.0.0.1:3000/` in the browser still shows me `nginx` welcome page, even though I made a restart to the `nginx` service.

Comment: Test the configuration using `nginx -T`. But `index.html;` is not a legal statement, did you mean `index index.html;`?

Comment: Perhaps stating the obvious, but is there a firewall active? Type `iptables -L` (as root) to check.

Comment: @RichardSmith, my mistake. I fixed it, but still same results happen.

Comment: @maulinglawns, nothing to worry about, I think. But I will post it in the question. Would you please check it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue; the problem was that I have not included `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/` in `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` in order to load configs from. After a `restart` on the `nginx` service, my web application was completely deployed.

I should mention that I also checked the output of command `nginx -t` in order to be sure every change in the `nginx` configurations are OK; the output for a successful re-configuration is:

```
nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful
```

BTW, this is my nginx configurations now:

```
user  nginx;
worker_processes  1;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                  '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                  '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    keepalive_timeout  65;

    #gzip  on;

#    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```